# Downloading Excel file in Internet Explore through selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, download, webdriver

I have to automate a case in which I have to download an excel file using selenium ide.I have done this in firefox by using custom profile feature which automatically download file and save it into a user defined folder. To do the same in Internet explorer, is there any thing in IE like custom profile and preferences? how do I prompt IE to automatically download a file..I am using java for automation..Kindly help..

Comment: you can download file to specified folder using this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it easily in IE, there's no profile to configure.

That said, you can try:

- downloading the file directly using [this](https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java) (or any other similar WebDriver-friendly tool), if you can. That will totally cut IE out of the process.
- see [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) about the same thing, just generic Java and not WebDriver.
- if everything fails, you can try blindly pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after clicking the download, [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) helps with this. But you can't really specify the folder.